# Python scp/paramiko Bad Time Format Exception when attempting to get a file

Tags: python, paramiko, scp

Python 3.9
scp 0.14.4
running on Mac OSX Ventura 13.0

When trying to run the following:

```
def createSSHClient(server, port, user, password):
    client = SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, user, password)
    return client


def get_file():
    ssh = createSSHClient('myhost.com', 2022, 'username', 'mypassword')
    banner = ssh.exec_command('\n')
    scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
    scp.get(remote_path='/mnt/users/username/file.txt', local_path='./file.txt', preserve_times=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_file()
```

The following exception is being thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/projects/diet/scp-example/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scp.py", line 437, in _set_time
    mtime = int(times[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'his'
```

This seems to be trying to parse the banner or something? Even though I indicate not to preserve times so not sure why its attempting it.

This is the banner returned once the host is listed:

```
Unauthorized use of this system is prohibited.  Anyone using this
system expressly consents to the monitoring of his or her system use
and understands that evidence of criminal activity discovered by
system personnel may be reported to law enforcement officials.
```

Thus I was thinking the 'his' was being picked up out of the banner.

Tried slipping in a command prior to the scp get on the client but probably didn't really do much as I suspect the scp still gets the banner.

when I manually do this via the cli all works fine

Any thoughts on this would be great

Comment: This is probably not Python issue, but rather server issue. Can you `scp` from the server at all? And why are you trying SCP? Why not SFTP?

Comment: Agreed its not a python issue, however, something in the scp python package isn't happy so was wondering if I just maybe missed a setting or something

Comment: To directly answer your question, sftp is pretty locked down and or blocked, but scp is avail for whatever reason... I just wanted to use this to copy down a series of files from a directory that contains some exported data.

Comment: Yes it is, as stated in the question "when I manually do this via the cli all works fine"

Comment: If you go to `_set_time` in `scp.py` and insert `print(cmd)` at the very beginning, what do you get? Btw the "T" must be capital, otherwise it would get to `_set_time`. So it's not your banner. + Verbose output (`-vvv`) of `scp` download would be useful. + Doing logging/`print` after every `send[all]` and `recv` would be very useful too.

Comment: This helped. I was able to see that a message was returned indicating that the server only supported sftp? Yet for some weird reason I can use scp via the cli. Maybe there is some weird routing going on and I'm hitting a different host than what I'm thinking.

Comment: Aren't you using the very latest OpenSSH? Since 9.0, the `scp` uses SFTP by default – https://superuser.com/q/1434225/213663 + Note that before you wrote that *"sftp is ... blocked"*. It seems that it was false information. In any case, you did not have  [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the first place (what I assumed).

Comment: Well, I'll claim some ignorance in this area. As for what version I would believe so on it. Also didn't know how all that really worked under the hood. I think I'll go with the original suggestion you posted and just use sftp since its for an internal project. So sftp isn't blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using two different libraries to access the file

For paramiko you can use the following to get the file

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remotepath='/mnt/users/username/file.txt', localpath='file.txt')
```

rather than

```
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
scp.get(remote_path='/mnt/users/username/file.txt', local_path='./file.txt', preserve_times=False)
```

Comment: I was following the example posted here. https://pypi.org/project/scp/
sftp is ok, but wanted to use scp for this exercise.

Comment: Agreed two different libraries however, the scp pypi is using paramiko from what I read in the git repo.

Comment: @millerwa I'm not able to reproduce the error in my end. I dont think the banner message is causing the error. Both SCP and SSH is working.

Comment: I hate it when that happens... wondering if there is something environmental then interfering.

Comment: Well defn tried your suggestion with sftp which did work. I did a little more digging and for whatever reason there was a message coming back from the host (I assume) that indicated that only sftp was allowed? But yet for whatever reason I was able to scp the file(s). So not exactly sure what/why but will continue on with sftp instead.